# Sirloin Tip Kebab cooking times

Tags: beef, grilling, kebab

I want to make some Beef Kebabs with onion, sirloin and peppers. I'm using metal skewers (if that helps). How long should I let the Sirloin cook on the kebabs? There is bite size pieces on a grill at 350 degrees F. I want to cook 6 kebabs. Any ideas?

Edit:

1. I like my meat medium-rare.
2. My grill itself is 6 inches from the heat.
3. The pieces are no bigger than 2x2 inches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for us to give you absolute cooking times. There are too many variables, among them:

- How do you like your meat cooked?
- How hot is your fire?
- How far are the kabobs from the fire (since kabob cooking is essentially 100% radiation heating, distance is a huge factor)
- What is the size of your meat chunks?
- What is the starting temperature of your meat chunks?

You will note that the *number* of kabobs is not a factor.

Instead, you need to learn to check for when they are done to your liking. This will come from experience.  Kabobs are generally too small to use a thermometer on; you would need a very high quality one like a Thermapen in order to get a reasonable reading.

All that said, it is likely that you want something on the order of 2-3 minutes per side, but there are far too many factors to make that a concrete recommendation.

You can start by cooking just one kabob, or even one chunk.   When you think it looks good, try it.  Of it is overcooked, do the next one for less time; undercooked, cook a little longer.  After a couple, you will know about how long you will need for your particular set of circumstances.

Comment: From my edit above can you tell me anything differently?

Comment: Not really, those are fairly average values, although 6 inches from the fire seems pretty far.  This is not something where someone can specify a time.  You are going to need to practice and learn to recognize when they are done to your liking.